# Missing argument for parameter in call, Binding value issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a binding value in a view. Whenever I do this is gives a compiling error in the PreviewProvider. The error is shown in the last code bit.

I cant add the argument (showProfile: $showProfile) because it cannot find it in the scope.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var showMenu = false
@Binding var showProfile: Bool

var body: some View {
    
    
    let drag = DragGesture()
        .onEnded {
            if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showMenu = false
                }
            }
        }
```

//MARK: View Start

```
return NavigationView {
         GeometryReader { geo in
            
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
            MainView()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geo.size.width/2 : 0)
                .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                
            if self.showMenu {
                MenuView()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
               }
                
            }
            
            .gesture(drag)
            
            
         } .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                                
                                Button(action: {
            
                                    withAnimation {
                                        self.showMenu.toggle()
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                                        .imageScale(.large)
                                }
                          )
        )}
    }
}
```

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

```
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView() // <---- Error, missing argument for parameter 'showProfile' in call
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined a `@Binding` on `ContentView`, you need to always provide a value for it. In a preview, you'll most likely want to pass it a `.constant` value:

```
ContentView(showProfile: .constant(true))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?